# Will it be possible to render out the Workbench viewports in Blender 2.8?

Tags: rendering, 3d-view, npr, workbench-render-engine

In the same way as you can currently render the active viewport in Open GL? Some aspects of the Workbench renderer look as if they will be very useful for NPR people.

Comment: It's still implemented in OpenGL so I don't see any reason why not. In fact, it's the same like a screenshot, also in terms of quality.

Comment: Thanks - since NPR renders often go through a lot of 2D post-processing anyway, resolution isn't always an issue.

Comment: how are you able to render the active viewport in openGL style nowadays?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Blender 2.80 the workbench engine can be used as an interactive viewport renderer, viewport rendering (to image or animation) or final render (image or animation.

**Interactive Viewport**

Workbench is used when the viewport is in `Solid` mode.

**Viewport Rendering**

In the view menu there are two operations. One for `Viewport Render Image` and one for `Viewport Render Animation` it will use the same settings as your current viewport.

**Workbench as render engine**

In the Properties panel it is possible to set the render engine to `Workbench`. Now when you do a final rendering it will use the workbench engine.