# How can I make entire scene and materials shadeless in Blender 3.3.3?

Tags: modeling, rendering, objects, shaders, lighting

I have designed a building in Blender as a 3D model and assigned all the textures to it already but I don't want to have to worry about lighting... How can I make it where the building isn't affected by light and is shadeless?

[image: Viewport render from left side]
[image: Viewport render from right side]

Solved: All I had to do was disable shadows for all lights and it got the end result I was looking for... Thanks for the help :)

Comment: If you're talking about the Rendered disaply mode, you can go into the Viewport Shading panel and disable Scene Lights and Scene World and your scene will be enlight by the HDRI of the Material Preview, is it what you want?

Comment: or. just plug your textures straight into material output without going through a shader, first?

Comment: @moonboots Well the viewport doesn't really matter, I just want the final render to be shadeless... I will edit my post and attach a screenshot...

Comment: @RobinBetts I already made the textures and it would be hard to go through each one and edit... I just want the whole scene rendered with no light effect...

Comment: do you have some reference images of what you want? Without light effect you won't see any volume

Comment: @moonboots basically I just want to get rid of shadows... I want the lighting to be the same all the way around so I don't have to decide where to put the sun... This isn't supposed to be an artistic photo, just a 3D model for a building we are making... Something like material preview, but I want the windows to still be transparent so you can see other objects...

Comment: Try workbench render with lighting set to flat.

Comment: @TheLabCat how do I do that?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Will it be possible to render out the Workbench viewports in Blender 2.8?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/107765/will-it-be-possible-to-render-out-the-workbench-viewports-in-blender-2-8)

Comment: @Emir it does, but then it gets rid of the color... I want the color to be there and the windows but not the shadows...

Comment: @TheLabCat as you can see with my comment to Emir, it won't work because of the colors and windows not being existent...

Comment: You can add colors to the viewport, every material has this option all the below the material options

Comment: What about windows? Seems confusing... Is there any YouTube links or tutorials that could help me out here?